# Neo4j and neomodel are throwing unique exception on single parameter

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo, neomodel

I am populating a database and I have these this model:

```
class Album(StructuredNode):
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=False, required=True)
    artist = StringProperty(unique_index=False, required=True)
    slug = StringProperty(unique_index=True, required=True)
```

But for some reason when I try to populate my database, if I have two albums with the same name but different artists and slugs, I get this error:

```
File "/Users/datascientist/Desktop/populate.py", line 66, in <module>
  album.save()   
File "/Users/datascientist/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/signals.py", line 25, in hooked
  val = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/datascientist/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/core.py", line 159, in save
  self._id = self.create(self.__properties__)[0]._id
File "/Users/datascientist/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/core.py", line 289, in create
  results = db.cypher_query(query, params)
File "/Users/datascientist/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 216, in cypher_query
  raise UniqueProperty(e.message)
```

neomodel.exception.UniqueProperty

How do I make it so the name parameter isn't unique?

Comment: I realize that combining album and artist into a single line like ("album" + " ..... " + artist) would work, but I'd like to know a more appropriate solution

Comment: That error might be expected if you are trying to create multiple albums with the same `slug` value, since `slug` is declared to be unique. Are you sure that you are not trying to do that?

Comment: slug is supposed to be unique and it is, the problem is when album is the same as another, like many albums have the same title. The slug is album-artist so it is never the same as another.

Comment: So, if an artist re-releases an album (say, after remastering), it is guaranteed to have a new name?

Comment: yes, according to my database.  Either way, the error is being thrown in a specific instance where they have different artists and slugs but the same name.